# Is there a way to set the encoding for NLog syslog SyslogTarget message

Tags: c#, nlog, .net-standard, syslog

I am using NLog.Targets.Syslog (6.0.0) in order to create syslog target on the fly and write messages to it. Is there a way to set the encoding? (e.g. - For File target there is a Encoding property).

```
 NLog.Targets.Syslog.SyslogTarget syslogTarget = new NLog.Targets.Syslog.SyslogTarget() {
                    Layout = Constants.RESPONSE.SYS_LOG.LAYOUT,
                    Name = Constants.RESPONSE.SYS_LOG.IDENTITY
                };
```

I'm using c#, netstandard2.0

Comment: Have a look at github repo [NLog.Targets.Syslog](https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog) for supported options

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski Yes. Didn't find there

Comment: Isn't UTF-8 mandatory in Syslog? "The content field should be encoded in a UTF-8" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog

Comment: Looks like Rfc5424 prefers to use UTF8 and Rfc3164 prefers use ASCII.